# EventListener add and remove not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my sample code is not working perfectly can you please check and let me know where I'm wrong?

```
function clickButon (){
    var btn = document.getElementById('updateText');
     btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        updateHTml();
        console.log('event click here ')
       // jsFileLoad();
     },true)
     
}    
function eventRemove(){
    var btn = document.getElementById('updateText');
    btn.removeEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('event remove for btn')
    }, true)
}
window.onload = function(){
    clickButon();

    setTimeout(function(){
        eventRemove();
    }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working perfect" ?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the event handler, you have to pass the same function that you passed when adding it.

For example, here you would successfully remove the event handler

```
function sameFunction() {
  console.log('test');
}

btn.addEventListener(sameFunction)
btn.removeEventListener(sameFunction)
```

Contraty to creating a new function when you're removing the event listener:

```
function sameFunction() {
  console.log('test');
}
    
btn.addEventListener(sameFunction)
btn.removeEventListener(function() {
  console.log('test');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Victor Santizo i understand you logic and thanks for guide me  :)

Comment: You're welcome, consider marking the answer as accepted that way it can help others too :) @RohitAzadMalik

Answer (score 1):

The function you are removing is not the same function you added. The only way to remove a listener is to give it the same function that is already added as a listener. For example:

```js
function updateTextClickListener(evt) {
  console.log('event click here')
}

function installUpdateTextClickListener() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('updateText');
  btn.addEventListener('click', updateTextClickListener, true)
}    
function uninstallUpdateTextClickListener() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('updateText');
    btn.removeEventListener('click', updateTextClickListener, true)
}
window.onload = function(){
  installUpdateTextClickListener();

  setTimeout(function(){
    uninstallUpdateTextClickListener();
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<button id="updateText">Update Text</button>
```

Note that if you create an identical function, it will still not work, because "identical" is not "same":

```js
const first  = function() { return 42; }
const second = function() { return 42; }

console.log(first === first)
// true
console.log(first === second)
// false
```

Comment: Thanks @Amadan i understand you logic and thanks for guide me :)